# using setValue(value, forKey) for generic property

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following sample code:

```
class A<T> : NSObject {
    var value: T? = nil
}

class B<T> : NSObject {
    private var _value: T? = nil
    var value: AnyObject?{
        get{
            return _value as? AnyObject
        }
        set{
            _value = newValue as? T
        }
    }
}

var obj = B<Int>()
print(obj.value) // "nil"
obj.setValue(5, forKey: "value")
print(obj.value!) // "5"
```

This works fine if I use `B` class. However, my target is to use smaller class `A` which I can't use because of the exception thrown on the `setValue` function:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value

Is there is a way to pass value to the generic property in the `setValue` function? And if it is official restriction, where I can read about this?